# how to import csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have downloaded the required csv file but don't know how to import the file into pandas using python.

1. Construct in Python four data frames (df1, df2, df3, df4) to store the four data sets (I, II, III, IV). Each dataset consists of eleven (x,y) points;
   [.5 Marks]
2. Find the basic descriptive statistics in Python using the method describe();
   [.5 Marks]

Comment: "pandas" has the function "read_csv" for that.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried with pandas so far ?

Comment: Welcome! I share with you this useful guide to create questions that increase your possibilities to get the answer you are looking for: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to create panda DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("dataset1")
df2 = pd.read_csv("dataset2")

#descriptive statistics
df1.describe()
```

Comment: I have tried that and it says "dataset1" is not defined

Comment: i have downloaded the csv file and it's located in my downloads

Comment: Give complete path of dataset1 like 'users/downloads/dataset1'

Comment: i have now done that, thank you